# What is the function of a self-closing <nowiki/> tag in Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, tags

The [#loop](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Loops#.23loop) parser function from the Loops extension contains a `<nowiki/>` tag in a code example:

```
{{#loop: varname
  | 4
  | 4
  | <nowiki/>
* This is round {{#var:varname}} and we have {{#expr: 7- {{#var:varname}}}} more to go
}}
```

What does the `<nowiki/>` tag do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stops the parser from eating whitespace at the beginning of the template parameter. The `*` needs to be at the beginning of the line (ie. preceded by a newline) to be turned into a list.